# Get Build.BuildNumber variable in gradle

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, build.gradle, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

In Compilation Definition I'm using GitVersion for generate SemVer, the main idea is tu use the value inside the build.gradle. I wasn't unable to find a way to inject the TFS variables into gradle environment.

Comment: What's the Compilation Definition? Are you using TFS  [Build: Gradle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/gradle) task? Such as [Gradle build using VSTS/TFS](https://srivatsamarichi.wordpress.com/2016/08/28/gradle-build-using-vststfs/)

Comment: I'm using that Gradle build task from TFS, and what I need to do is to inject variables to be used inside gradle scripts.

Comment: Do you try to specify it in Options? [Build: Gradle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/gradle)